# Struts - Is it possible to reference some value from the jsp page inside a <var-value> tag in validation.xml?

Tags: xml, validation, struts

When a field is not valid I need to display a message like : *"The field 'MyFieldName' is not valid"*.

Problem is : **'MyFieldName' is not in a property file** because it is dynamic (it comes from the database). So it it just written somewhere in my JSP.

Question is : How do I tell struts validation.xml to **GET** and inject 'MyFieldName' in the error message ?

I wish we could do something like this :

```
<field property="myFieldInput" depends="required">
    <arg name="required" key="${var:myFieldName}" resource="false" position="0" />
    <var>
        <var-name>myFieldName</var-name>
        <var-value>magicFonction.getFieldNameFor('myFieldInput')</var-value>
    </var>
</field>
```

If nothing allows to natively do that, any workaround would be fine.
For what I understand about validation with struts, it seems impossible, but I have to ask.

I use struts 1.2 (yes it is old, so is the application I am working on).